# Laravel submit form return 404

Tags: laravel-5

@csrf is in the form
A route exists  confirmed through route:list
Control is not transferred to the controller I have used exit as a first line of code in the controller method.
Get routes are working fine
Form submission URL is simple  like
Route::post('/admin_login_submit', 'Admin\LoginController@admin_login_submit')->name('admin_login_submit');

I have tried to submit simple form through view

Comment: Url is not added to VerifyCsrfToken in middleware

Comment: Please share your form, controller and route code.